# T-SQL TRIGGER FOR DELETE ошибка

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Пытаюсь сделать аккумулятор продаж. При каждом добавлении и удалении записей в `JOR_SALES` кол-во в `ACC_SALES` должно обновляться. С `INSERT` все работает по такой же схеме. А `DELETE` выдает ошибку **обновление воздействует на 3 строки**. В чем может быть причина?

```
create trigger acc_del
on jor_sales for  delete
as 
DECLARE @minus int
declare @old int

select @minus = coalesce((select sum(cnt) from deleted),0)
select @old = (select cnt from ACC_SALES where id=1)

update ACC_SALES set cnt = @old-@minus where id=1
```

--Добавил--

Проблема где-то в последней строке. Если ее закомментировать, проблем с удалением строк нет. Причина все еще не ясна

Comment: `where id=1` - ??

Comment: @Igor, да. Не добавлять а обновлять. Только одно число

Comment: update можно было бы записать как `update ACC_SALES set cnt=cnt-(select sum(cnt) from deleted) where id=1`. Но я все равно не понимаю откуда может браться ошибка про которую вы пишите

Comment: @Mike, знал бы - не спрашивал)) Что самое обидное - работает с Инсертом. На счет сокращения - согласен, набирал код для демонстрации, так лучше видно "издалека"

Comment: Может оно и лучше видно, но между `select @old=...` и update в таблице может что то изменится и вы используете неверное значение cnt. После записи одним запросом, ничего не изменилось, ошибка та же ?

Comment: Да, проблема та же. Не помогает и вариант с добавлением  `insert into ACC_SALES (cnt) values( -(select sum(cnt) from deleted)+(select cnt from ACC_SALES where id=1))` (думал, может `update` формально содержит в себе удаление и идет два удаления) Пробовал дописывать имя таблиц перед точкой. Все к одному...

Answer (score 1):

Я в шоке! Причиной оказался счетчик строк. После его отключения все заработало. Вставлю код, может, кому-то пригодится (оставлю свой вариант, хотя **Mike** прав на счет подстановки выборки "на лету")

```
create trigger acc_del
on jor_sales for  delete
as
```

### set nocount on

```
DECLARE @minus int
declare @old int

select @minus = coalesce((select sum(cnt) from deleted),0)
select @old = (select cnt from ACC_SALES where id=1)

update ACC_SALES set cnt = @old-@minus where id=1
```